# Confusion in discontinuous function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continuity

This Graph confused me...my doubt are these

[image]

- What is the value of the function at t=1, is it 1 or 5?
- Why they have included 1 for $x^2$ but not for 6-x (like $x\geq1)$,it should be x>=1 too they have exclused it why?
- If a random function is given like this which limit I have to include and which limit have to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition says that $f(1)=1$ because the value $x=1$ is included in the $x^2$ clause (where it says $x\leq 1$) and excluded in the $6-x$ clause (where it says $x>1$).  If they had included $x=1$ in the $6-x$ clause also, then they would not have defined a function, because they would have given two different values, 1 and 6, for $f(1)$.

The choice of which clause should include $x=1$ is arbitrary.  You could define another function $g$ exactly like $f$ except that $x=1$ is excluded in the first clause and included in the second. But that would be a **different** function because $g(1)\neq f(1)$.

Comment: Suppose this function graph is given without $f(x)$...then i can Include 1 for 6- x or x^2 that will be my choice?

Comment: If I were given this graph, without the definition of $f$ and without any other indication of an intended value for $f(1)$, then I'd assume that $f(1)$ is undefined, i.e., that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R-\{1\}$.

Comment: Please have a look this was my actual doubt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485305/addition-of-two-piecewise-function

Answer (score 1):

(1) By *definition* of $f$, $f(1) = 1^2$ because $1\le 1$.

(2) Any function definition is arbitrary. But you can't give *two different* values for the function in the *same* point.

(3) Same answer that (2).

Comment: Suppose this function graph is given without $f(x)$...then how will you write the fucntion f(x)?

Comment: @USER786, you can't extract a function of an arbitrary graph.

Comment: Perez Pinilla Please have a look this was my actual doubt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485305/addition-of-two-piecewise-function