# Addition of two piecewise function

Tags: functions, arithmetic, piecewise-continuity, continuity

Suppose I have function

> $$y(x)=\begin{cases}
>  x+1\qquad & 0\leq x\leq1 \\
>  2-x\qquad &  1<x \leq2 \\
> 0\qquad & \mathrm{elsewhere}
> \end{cases}$$
>   I need to find the function $g(x)=y(x+2)+2y(x+1)$

---

$$y(x+2)=\begin{cases}
 x+3\qquad &-2\leq x\leq-1 \\
 -x\qquad &  -1<x \leq0 \\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$$2y(x+1)=\begin{cases}
 2x+4\qquad & -1\leq x\leq0\\
 2-2x\qquad &  0<x \leq1 \\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Now,
$$g(x)=y(x+2)+2y(x+1)=\begin{cases}
 x+3\qquad & -2\leq x\leq -1 \\
 x+4\qquad &  -1<x \leq0 \\
2-2x\qquad &0<x\leq1\\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Now the result looks Okay,

But the problem is the value of $y(x+2)$ at $x=-1$ is $2$ and $2y(x+2)$ at $x=-1$ is also $2$ so if I add both then $y(x+2)+2y(x+1)$ at $x=-1$ will be $2+2=4$,but the value of $g(x)$ at $x=-1$ is $-1+3=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
g_1(x)=y(x+2)=\begin{cases}
x+3&\text{ for }-2\le x\le -1\\
-x&\text{ for }-1< x\le0\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
g_2(x)=2y(x+1)=\begin{cases}
2x+4&\text{ for }-1\le x\le0\\
2-2x&\text{ for }0< x\le1\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Giving the result

\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x+3&\text{ for }-2\le x<-1\\
3x+7&\text{ for }x=-1\\
x+4&\text{ for }-1< x\le0\\
2-2x&\text{ for }0< x\le1\\
0&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Now we see that $g_1(-1)=2,\,g_2(-1)=2$ and $g(-1)=4$.

Answer (score 1):

In your calculation of $g(x)$, the first line, $x+3$, was obtained by adding $y(x+2)=x+3$ and $2y(x+1)=0$.  The first of these two equations, $y(x+2)=x+3$, is valid for $x$ in the range $-2\leq x\leq-1$. The second, $2y(x+1)=0$, is valid when $x<-1$ and also when $x>1$. In particular, it is **not** valid when $x=-1$.  So the $x+3$ line in your formula for $g(x)$ is not valid for $x=-1$ but only for $-2\leq x<-1$.

More generally, when you combine several formulas, each f which is valid for a certain range of $x$ values, then the combination will in general only be valid for those $x$ values that are in **all** the relevant ranges simultaneously.

Comment: $2y(x+1)$ is 0 for $ x<-1$ that is Okay but its defined at$ x=-1(-1\leq x\leq0$) why are you saying it not valid at $x=-1$? ............also please can you suggest something that I can read about these function I mean how to do this type of fucntion without confusion.

Comment: The formula $2y(x+1)=0$ is not valid at $x=-1$ because, when you put $x=-1$ in $2y(x+1)$, you get $2y(0)$, and the definition of the function $y$ says that $y(0)=1$ (because it says $y(x)=x+1$ whenever $0\leq x\leq1$).  The only thing I can really suggest that you read about this is the definitions of the functions in question. You seem to be assuming that, if some formula (like $2y(x+1)=0$) is valid for $x$ in some range, then it should remain valid also for the endpoints of that range. Whether that happens depends entirely on the definitions of the functions, not on your wishes.